# What is the point of having a dense layer in a neural network with no activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am surprised by the default setting in `keras`:

```
keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=None, ...)
```

Why do we have the option of only using a dense layer (which is matrix multiplication) but without an activation function (non-linear transformation)? I think these two should always go together in a neural network. Is there another case where we can use a dense layer without an activation function?

Comment: A fully connected neural network without an activation function is a multi layer perceptron model as it has only linear transformation of an input.
A perceptron model does the same

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One such scenario is the output layer of a network performing regression, which should be naturally linear. [This tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/) demonstrates this case.

Another case that comes to my mind are deep linear networks which are often being used in neural networks literature as a toy model for studying some phenomena that would be too complex with usual non-linear networks.

Comment: thanks for your answer! this make sense and we always use Dens(number of classes) in last layer.

Answer (score 8):

Another purpose of using linear layers is to reduce dimensionality (and the number of parameters). For example the [Skip-gram and CBOW model for word embeddings](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf).
[image]
The training task is to predict context words of a given word $p(w_o|w_i)$. A naive way is to count the occurrences of context words for each word and put them in a matrix $M$, then the probability is just $p(w_o|w_i) = f(M_{w_i})_{w_o}$, where $f$ is a normalization function.

The problems is often the number of words $n$ is huge and we can't afford an $n$ by $n$ matrix. So we can first use an $n$ by $d$ matrix $A$ to reduce the dimension (to say 128) and use another $d$ by $n$ matrix $B$ to turn it back, then number of parameters can be reduced to $2*d*n$. It's kind of like matrix decomposition in the sense that we use $BA$ to approximate $M$.

The model can be implemented as two linear layers followed by a normalization function and can be trained using the cross-entropy loss $E[y_n\log f(BAw_i)]$, where for the Skip-gram model, $w_i$ is a one-hot vector, for the CBOW model, $w_i$ is a BOW vector.

Comment: +1 so, learning embeddings usually will not be "after activation"?, the numbers in the embedding vector is usually form -inf to inf?

Comment: @hxd1011 thanks, I'm not an expert but I think it depends on the problem, I have seen people use normalized embeddings as well.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a network for either a binary classification task. One way to implement this is using a final activation that yields predicted probabilities (non-negative, sum to 1). An inverse logistic function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}$ is one way to do this in the binary case.

Using the standard binary cross-entropy loss $\mathcal{L}=-\sum_i y_i \log(\hat{y}_i)+(1-y_i)\log(1-\hat{y}_i)$ means that we're round-tripping exponential functions and logarithmic functions. This can cause a severe loss of precision due to accumulated numerical error.

On the other hand, working on the scale of $x$ instead of the probability scale eliminates the round-tripping. In other words, using an identity function the final layer, and a loss function that works on the scale of the linear predictor, achieves the same model without loss of precision.

We can extend the same reasoning to the case of a $k$-nary classification task with a softmax activation.

See: [Numerical computation of cross entropy in practice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/475589/numerical-computation-of-cross-entropy-in-practice)

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use activation=None, you for example add a BatchNormalization layer before you actually use the activation. This is used often in convolutional neural networks, but is good for dense neural networks as well.

```
z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation=None)(z)
z = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(z)
z = tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu")(z)
```

Answer (score -1):

You always want the most flexibility that is possible out of the library that you are using. For example, if you want to have a deep NN with skipped connections ( see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385) ) you need to apply your activation function after the operation F(x) + x is done. how can you implement that on a dense layer with the output F(x) that has no option to stop it from applying activation function before you can do the summation?